# Proof verification - A specific function $f$ has non-zero derivative at $0$ but is not monotone in any interval around $0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, monotone-functions

Here's a problem on a function that has non-zero derivative at the point $0,$ but is not monotone in *any* interval around the point $0$. I'm stating the problem and presenting my solution to it.

**I'd greatly appreciate if someone checks the solution and tell me if there's any gap in my arguments. Also, is there any method/trick that may enable me produce a shorter solution? Thank you.**

> **The Problem :** 
>   Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
>   $f(x)=
> \begin{cases} 
>       x+2x^2sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) & x\neq 0 \\
>       0 & x=0
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> To show that $f'(0)=1,$ but $f$ is not monotonic in any interval around $0$.

**My Solution :** We see that

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0;~x \neq 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0;~x \neq 0} \frac{x+2x^2sin\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)}{x}=1+2\lim_{x \to 0}xsin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$

We first find out $\lim_{x \to 0}xsin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$. Let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then
$$x \in (-\delta,\delta)\setminus\{0\} \implies \left| xsin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)-0 \right| \leq |x| < \delta=\epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $\lim_{x \to 0}xsin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=0$. And hence,

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ exists and is equal to $1+(2 \times 0)=1$. Thus $f'(0)=1$.

---

Now, let $\alpha>0$ be arbitrary. By *Archimedean Property $2,$*

$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<2\pi\alpha,$ i.e. $\frac{1}{2\pi N}<\alpha$.

Choose $x_1=\frac{1}{2\pi N},~x_2=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}},~x_3=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}$. Then, $x_1>x_2>x_3$. Now,

$f(x_1)=\frac{1}{2\pi N}+2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N}\Big)^2sin\Big(2\pi N\Big)=\frac{1}{2\pi N}$

$f(x_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big)^2sin\Big(2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big)^2$

$f(x_3)=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}+2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}\Big)^2sin\Big(2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}\Big)=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}-2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}\Big)^2$

*Claim :* $f(x_3)<f(x_1)<f(x_2)$

We see that $f(x_3)=\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}-2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}}\Big)^2 < \frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{3\pi}{2}} < \frac{1}{2\pi N} = f(x_1)$

Suppose $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$. Then,
\begin{align}
f(x_1) \geq f(x_2) &\iff \frac{1}{2\pi N} \geq \frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big)^2\\
&\iff \frac{1}{2\pi N} - \frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}} \geq 2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big)^2\\
&\iff \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{(2\pi N)(2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2})} \geq 2\Big(\frac{1}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big)^2\\
&\iff \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\pi N} \geq \frac{2}{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
&\iff \frac{2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2}}{2\pi N} \geq \frac{2}{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
&\iff 1+\frac{1}{4N} \geq \frac{4}{\pi}\\
&\iff \frac{1}{4N} \geq \frac{4}{\pi}-1=\frac{4-\pi}{\pi}\\
&\iff 4N \leq \frac{\pi}{4-\pi} < 4\\
&[\text{If not, let} \frac{\pi}{4-\pi} \geq 4 \iff \pi \geq 16-4\pi \iff 5\pi \geq 16 \iff \pi \geq 3.2, \text{ contradiction.}]\\
& \implies N<1
\end{align}

And we reach a contradiction. Hence $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$.

Thus the claim is true. We have $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in (0,\alpha)$ such that $x_1>x_2>x_3$ and $f(x_3)<f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. We conclude that $f$ is not monotone in $(0,\alpha),$ and hence in $(-\alpha,\alpha)$.

Since $\alpha>0$ is arbitrary, $f$ is not monotone in any interval around $0$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tiny little detail, when you write $$\lim_{x\to 0, x\neq 0}$$

the second part under the limit, i.e. $x\neq 0$, is unnecesary. When calculating $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, we **always** look only at values $f(x)$ for $x\neq a$. That's the whole point of a limit:

> By definition, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta >0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

(note the $0<|x-a|$ demands that $x\neq a$.

---

Also, I would prove that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ simply by showing that $$f(x_2)-f(x_1) = \frac{N\left(4\pi - \pi^2\right) - \frac{\pi^2}4}{\text{something}^2}$$

and that this number, because $4\pi - \pi^2 > 0$, is obviously positive for a large enough value of $N$.

---

Other than that, the proof is very well written and as far as I can see it, perfectly correct. Well done!

Comment: Thanks. I understand your point $($about not mentioning $x \neq 0$ in the limit$)$. And yes, directly computing $f(x_2)-f(x_1)$ seems to be easier. The quantity I get is $\frac{N(4\pi-\pi^2)-\frac{\pi^2}{4}}{2\pi N(2\pi N+\frac{\pi}{2})^2}$ which is greater than $0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Dragon Yup, that's the same quantity I get. Of course, the $)^2$ should be in the denominator, not outside the fraction...

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.